# Different ways of saying the same thing?

Tags: vocabulary, usage

Can the following be used interchangeably, and with like words such as treat/mistreat, use/misuse?

> A. You have incorrectly applied the concept.
>
> B. You have misapplied the concept.
>
> C. You have applied the concept in an incorrect way.
>
> 2.A Incorrectly spelled words.
>   2.B Misspelled words.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that examples A-C are equivalent in their meaning, differing only in their verbosity. If you're aiming for terse English, then B is the best. Incidentally, I would use 'manner' instead of 'way' in example C.

Note the difference between "You have incorrectly applied the concept" and "You have applied the incorrect concept".

2A and 2B are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was kind of odd no one answered for a long time. Now "You have incorrectly applied the concept" =You have used the right concept but the way you applied it to a situation/etc was incorrect. The other one is right application, wrong concept. Right?

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom: Your two statements in the comment are equivalent.